# How to use Dart's Difference Method and DateTime using a dynamic date?

Tags: dart, flutter

The application I'm building uses a sort of "Days since" counter using Duration Difference and DateTime, but I want the counter to begin on the day they started using the app by default, and have the option to put in whichever date they desire.

My Question is, how do i dynamically generate the start date of the counter to be the day they start using the app, and would this be easiest achieved with a database?

Comment: Anything you have tried? Any problems you encountered?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am relatively new to Flutter, so forgive my ignorance. But I was able to implement a working "days since" counter, but as far as I could figure out it seemed to only allow me to put in a single date that controlled the counter globally, instead of having a unique date for every user like I intended. As someone else mentioned, shared_preferences seems to be an option that could work and I'll try and work it in when I get back to my office. This app is very barebones for now and I'm trying to work out the functionality of my individual widgets as I go.

Comment: If you are using a database on a server anyway, you could store it there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so from my point of view a good way to do it seems to use `shared_preferences`. Shared preferences allow to store some key/value pair for the user, it's persistent and you can update it.

Here's the package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences

Here's a good article giving you details about it : https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/shared-preferences---how-to-save-flutter-application-settings-and-user-preferences-for-later-re-use/

The idea would be to create a function, checking if the key of `first_use_date` exists.

- If it does do nothing (or you can actually update it)
- If not you create it with the date of today.

Of course it's persistent since the app stays installed on the device.

For printing duration I let you check this class : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

And especially this method (which is not implemented yet) : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat/formatDurationFrom.html

Hope it's helps !!

Comment: And actually a database would not be appropriate for this kind of case since it's a single value you want to store.